# How to create a multi-tab details element in GitHub-flavoured markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown

So I have made an API. I want to document it. The API can be used in Java, Python, Javascript etc, and I want to show it in this tabular form (refer to image)[image: Something like this]

I want to host it on github

How can I make such a tabbed table?
(Image from: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html)

Comment: Can you please add a link to where you took the screenshot from?

Comment: @starball https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of this being possible. You can use the `<details>` element on GitHub, but that's only "one tab".

```
<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>
  contents
</details>
```